# Why VS Code is not giving the snippets for Unity Code

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am just a beginner. I am using **Unity Engine and VS Code.** When I open an Unity project, VS Code is not providing the **snippets**. Whether I Installed C#, Unity Snippets, Debugger for Unity etc. extensions. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with visual studio code but it can be weird. I highly recommend using visual studio 2017 or 2019. Community editions are free.

Try downloading visual studio 2019, also select and download "Game development with Unity" package.

After that in Unity go to Edit>Preferences>External tools>External Script Editor and select visual studio 2019. Let me know if VS 2019 does not show snippets.

Comment: I see some people who use **VS Code** with _Unity Engine_

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, Unity now has seamless integration with VSCode using its [Visual Studio Editor plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0/manual/index.html), which works alongside [Microsoft's official Unity extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudiotoolsforunity.vstuc). The last time I installed everything, I followed [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), and it worked.

*[Shameless Plug]* Regarding snippets, I use [Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets). It has a lot of snippets and it's configurable.